# Terraform - CosmosDB Unique Keys

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I've created a Cosmos DB through Terraform. It contains multiple containers with unique keys.

The problem is each time I create any new resource, for example: an app service or function app through Terraform, the unique keys in Cosmos DB gets deleted and recreated. Is there a way to stop this deletion and recreation of Cosmos DB each time, in Terraform?

Comment: Do you have any example of the TF code demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

hi you can create one or more unique_key  like this

```
  unique_key {
      paths = ["/Key1"]
    }

  unique_key {
      paths = ["/Key2"]
    }

  unique_key {
      paths = ["/Key3"]
    }
```